# Have the Kubuntu backports PPA stable software?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, ppa

I would like to update my KDE Desktop. I am using Kubuntu 11.10 with KDE 4.7, but I would like to install KDE 4.8.
I think that I have to add tne next PPA: **kubuntu-ppa/backports**, and then run **sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**.

Is the software in this PPA stable? If so, why is not a default repository?

Can I trust this PPA?

Thanks.

Ariel

Comment: Software in PPAs is usually untested by anyone other then the PPA owner and users. ...and the PPA description tells you as much.

Comment: if it makes you feel better, I've been using that PPA for a couple of months now and the only issue I've had is with my KMix dying sometimes, a restart solves this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Ubuntu Stable Release Updates**

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates

> Stable release updates are automatically recommended to a very large
>   number of users, and so it is critically important to treat them with
>   great caution. Therefore, when updates are proposed, they must be
>   accompanied by a strong rationale and present a low risk of
>   regressions.

**Kubuntu Backports**

https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports

> PPA description
>
> Backports of new versions of KDE and major KDE apps for Kubuntu which
>   are either too large a change or not yet tested enough to go to Ubuntu
>   Backports.

I think that the new version of the KDE is in the "too large category". The new backported KDE version is also build against the new version of the Qt.

**Q&A**

> Can I trust this PPA?

The packages are backported by the same Kubuntu developers who are building the Kubuntu 12.04 packages.

But there is always the risk ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports ):

> When using Backports, it is important to understand that there is an
>   inherent risk in backporting software. Although backported packages
>   are tested by the community before they are included in the
>   repository, there are very occasionally bad interactions with the
>   older software on your system that are overlooked...